# how to solve java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:

Tags: java, database, eclipse, derby, sqlexception

Good Morning everyone,

I have an issue trying to get my database working. I'm working with Eclipse and Apache Derby 10.12.1.1.
When I'm in the Database Developement Perspective I have no trouble connecting to my database and editing my table.
[Picture of Connected DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0c10U.png)

To connect to the Database I use the Derby Embedded JDBC Driver Version 10.2. But when I try to access my Database from a java program it gives me an SQLException: no suitable driver found.
Here is my code:

```
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:.../DB/db;create=false");

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERS.USERID = 123456");
        int i = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + rs.getString(1) + ", " + rs.getString(2));
            i++;
        }
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

and the ErrorMassage looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:.../DB/db;create=false
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at scraping/other.Test3.main(Test3.java:12)
```

Can someone help me?

Kind Regards,

Patty23

Comment: I saw you using derby, you may check the classpath. It will using setEmbeddedCP.bat in the %JAVA_HOME%\db, check it and make sure it will be :
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\db\lib\derby.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\db\lib\derbytools.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\db\lib\derbyoptionaltools.jar;
may have help for you.

Comment: or just change jdbc:derby:<database name>;create=true

Comment: I forgot to put the derby.jar file in the build path of the project. So that's now done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Problem was solved by adding the driver to the Build Path of the Javaproject.

Kind regards,
Patty23